# Winforms group datagridview value and checkboxlist

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview with 4 columns:  UserID,FirstName,LastName,Email.  The data is retrieved from the SQL database.  I currently have 10 records for this table.  I also have a checkedlist box with a long list of values (roles).

***My goal:***
Based on a record/row selected from the datagridview, certain checkboxes will be checked from the list.  For example, one UserID might have the 5th, 10th, and 12th role checkbox marked, while another UserID who might be a manager would have the first 10 checked.  The whole checklistbox shows in any case, just with different boxes checked.  I should see those same values if I exit out and back in.  To see if it makes life easier, I have a textbox that displays the UserID based on the datagridview row I select thinking maybe I could link that with the checkboxlist.  But I think the right way is to use the datagrid values.

How can I do this?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SampleDataGrid
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlDataAdapter adap;
        DataSet ds;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Search";
            button1.Text = "Search";
            try
            {
                con = new SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=My Data Source";
                con.Open();
                adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select RowID as 'ID',UserID as 'User ID', FirstName as 'First Name', LastName as 'Last Name', email as 'E-mail' from JoshTestTable", con);
                ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
                adap.Fill(ds, "User_Details");
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var cmbl = new SqlCommandBuilder(adap);
                adap.Update(ds, "User_Details");
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated.", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }


        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
 try
            {
                con = new SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = "My Connection String";
                con.Open();
                adap = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT JoshRoleTable.RoleID,JoshRoleTable.RoleName FROM Josh_REL_Table INNER JOIN JoshRoleTable ON Josh_REL_Table.RoleID = JoshroleTable.RoleID WHERE JoshTestTable.UserID like '%" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "%' ", con);
                ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
                adap.Fill(ds, "User_Details");
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

                textBox1.Text = row.Cells["User ID"].Value.ToString();
            }


        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

                textBox1.Text = row.Cells["User ID"].Value.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "My Data Source";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select UserID, FirstName,LastName,Email FROM JoshTestTable where UserID like '%" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "%' OR  FirstName like '%" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "%' OR  LastName like '%" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "%' OR  Email like '%" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "%' ", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }









    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you need some extra tables in your database to hold the "roles" data. It's a many to many relationship so JoshTestTable currently holds your user data. You will need another table that holds details of the roles so something like this:

Role:
RoleID (INT)
RoleName (VARCHAR)

Next a table to store the relationships so:

JoshTestTable_Role_REL:
RelationID (INT)
UserID (INT)
RoleID (INT)

Then in your dataGridView1_CellClick method you can query these new two tables to find out what roles that user has. Something like:

```
SELECT T2.RoleID, T2.RoleName
```

FROM JoshTestTable_Role_REL T1
INNER JOIN Role T2 ON T1.RoleID = T2.RoleID
WHERE T1.UserID = XXX

Where XXX is the UserID of the selected user.

You then loop through the records returned from the above query and enable / disable the check boxes accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I tried what you suggested.  I made the 3 tables with the columns you suggested.  I'll add to the cellclick method code above.  When I try running it (including through SQL), I get an error "the multi-part identifier JoshTestTable.UserID could not be bound.

Comment: Looks like I have to change my INNER JOIN .  Either I had a roleID to my TestTable (with the user information) or change it